# How to take advantage of @Security annotations from Symfony controllers for routes in Twig templates?

Tags: symfony, security, routes, annotations, twig

First of all, I'm working with Symfony 3.2. Ideally a solution also works for future or at least the latest releases (I'll update soon to 3.3), it maybe even works for the current LTS version 2.8.

---

Assuming you're having a role hierarchy for different access rights (`ROLE_USER`, `ROLE_MANAGER`, `ROLE_ADMIN` etc.). Now, you have one (or more) controller class(es) with several actions. Each action method is mapped to a route using `@Route` annotations, also each one is access protected using [Symfony's security annotations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-controllers-and-other-code) such as `@Security("has_role('ROLE_MANAGER')")`.

Example:

```
// ./src/YourBundle/Controller/AdminController.php

// ...

/**
 * @Route("/hello", name="admin-dashboard")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 */
public function helloAction()
{
    // ...
}

// ...
```

Let's say in some `base.html.twig` template there is a navigation snippet listing anchor links to all routes. But the links to secured routes shall only be rendered if the currently logged-in user has the appropriate user role (as already defined in the Controller class by using `@Security` annotation).

Now, what can I do to take benefit of the `@Security` annotations of my action methods? I don't always want to check for the same user role. Whenever I change the access level by changing the required user role in the `@Security` annotation I always have to ensure to update all references to that route. That's annoying and not very fail-safe.

Example of how I would do that normally:

```
{# ./src/YourBundle/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}

{# ... #}

<nav>
    {% if is_granted('ROLE_MASTER') %}
        <a href="{{ path('admin-dashboard') }}">Hello</a>
    {% endif %}
    <a href="{{ path('admin-other') }}">Other page<a>
</nav>

{# ... #}
```

How I wished I could check the access rights:

```
{# ./src/YourBundle/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}

{# ... #}

<nav>
    {% if is_granted_path('admin-dashboard') %}
        <a href="{{ path('admin-dashboard') }}">Hello</a>
    {% endif %}
    <a href="{{ path('admin-other') }}">Other page<a>
</nav>

{# ... #}
```

I am afraid that `@Route` and `@Security` do not correlate, do they? But if they do, how can I check a user's access rights to a route using just the route name like I do for linking to its path instead of checking the user's explicit role?

I can imagine to implement a new Twig helper function that I can pass a route's name to. Then the helper grabs the corresponding route using a router component. But then I don't know how to get the security setting for this route… Is that even possible? I somehow doubt, it would be nice though.

Answer (score 2):

Checking secured routes in controller have 2-staged workflow.

1. On controller action invocation, event listener checks the action and modify request (if there is @Security, @Template and so on annotations).
2. Then another event listener catches `FilterControllerEvent`, changed request and check the grant permissions.

Because of this, all checks are performed in run-time. It means impossible to just ask if the route has some granting permissions (without running controller's action).

But, as another approach, you can specify `access_control` section (e.g. in your `security.yml` file). Then write your own service, that will receive `@security.access_map` service. And implement your own twig function. It's not a big deal, but you will need to specify all grants in your security config file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
I already thought of there might be no real chance to easily do what I asked for. Yeah, a service providing a mapping of routes and "their" user roles (or even vice versa) would be pretty simple to realise. It's not the worst idea. Not exactly what I had in mind because you still have to configure the mapping instead of "just" grabbing the annotations' security definitions.  
I am curious about more answers. So please bear with me for not accepting your answer as the solution yet. :-)

Comment: I just came up with another idea. Instead of manually configuring the mapping as suggested by @e.k. it might be an approach to implement a new annotation class. I have something in mind like `@SecurityRoute`. This one could be an adapter for both `@Route` and `@Security` annotations and should therefore of course implement the appropriate interfaces. Internally that adapter could use a mapping service like the one @e.k. said. But that service won't get the information from security.yml but from the usage of the new annotation. … Not sure, if this could work, just a spontanious idea.